# error with phpMyAdmin using WAMP access denied

Tags: localhost, wamp

i am using **phpMyAdmin** in **WAMP** server i changed the root password and i tried to r-enter to the **phpMyAdmin** but the system display this error

**Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.**

if anyone can help me to fix this error i will appreciate this.
where to search in files to find this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have used phpMyAdmin to change the 'root' usernames password, you have to tell phpMyAdmin that you have made this change.

The normal instruction is to change these parameters like this:

**From:**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

This says the userid to use is 'root', there is no password, and you are aloowed to use a userid without a password

**To:**

This says the userid is 'root', the password is 'whatever you created as a password', and stops phpMyAdmin allowing the user of userids with no password.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your new password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

**My personal preference is to use these parameters instead:**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

This makes phpMyAdmin throw a userid/password challenge dialog every time you try to login.
You would use root as the userid and 'the password you setup' as the password.

I think this is even more secure as even if someone has access to your PC they cannot edit this file to see your super user password, as it is not actually recorded. It does mean you have to rememer it as once forgotten you are into a whole heep of hassle to get back into mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you user root has not password connect so. Try do it:

```
mysql_connect('server','user');
```

I hope this may help you.